# Problems with share play

Tags: ps4

When I play my ps4 in my own house,I use share play and it does a connection test and always comes on afterwards but I've been trying to use share play up my mum's which isn't far away from my home and we're both with the same service providers also we both have the same kind of download and upload speed.I'm BAFFLED lol! Can anyone give me some kind of answer,why this is happening? Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? You never mentioned it. Also what are you trying to share play with? We will need deeper details to help you efficiently.

Comment: I tried using share play on battlefront and in my home it was fine but when trying share play in my mum's on the same game it said connection too slow but it's the same speeds and I so that I use

Comment: We both have the same speeds on our broadband and are with the same isp aswell.

Comment: So you are trying to give a friend's ps4 the ability to play the game from your ps4 correct? You are not say trying to play it from a Vita?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to give a m8 the option to play the game from my ps4.. that's correct

Comment: So it all boils down to the connection and what people are doing on the connection. Maybe there is more traffic on the connection at your mom's compared to your own place.

Comment: I think your right m8 at least that's the way I see it anyway.thanks again

Comment: @Dupree3 yeah that's what I was thinking aswell,thanks for the feedback m8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically it just comes down to TRAFFIC as in how many people are online at the same time in certain areas playing the same modes as me! GOT IT.